# Adding a time unit to a timestamp using SQL and python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, time, timestamp

I am trying to add a number of hours to a timestamp in the following method in python

```
def add_hours(date, hour, duration):

    conn = database_connect()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    val = None

    start_time = date+" "+hour+":00:00"

    try:
       cur.execute("""SELECT timestamp %s + interval '%s hour' """,(start_time, duration))
       val = cur.fetchall()
    except:
       print("fetcherror")

    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return val
```

date and hour have been concatenated to a timestamp

(it looks like an SQL timestamp value: 2016-5-24 18:00:00)

I have looked at the postgreSQL documentation availiable here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html
and tested the query directly (it works fine)
Clearly my mistake is in the python handling of query but I can't figure out what it is.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL do you use? In the link you refer to version 8.0 which is from the dinosaur era.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the full interval variable, not only the number part. And best, use a datetime-object for your `start_time`:

```
start_time = datetime.datetime(2016, 05, 24, 12, 4, 0)
duration = 4
cur.execute("""SELECT timestamp %s + interval %s""", (start_time, '%s hours' % duration))
result = cur.fetchall()
# -> [(datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 24, 16, 4),)]
```

Comment: I have done start_time = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, 0, 0), where year, month, day and hour are all integers. the execute statement still does not work

Comment: My example results in `[(datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 24, 16, 4),)]`, so what have you done exactly.

Answer (score 0):

[@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37407719/131874) answer is correct and works for me. This is a bit simpler:

```
cur.execute ("""
    SELECT timestamp %s + %s * interval '1 hour' 
    """,
    (start_time, duration)
)
```